# Php sanitize before inserting data

Tags: php, pdo

How would i sanitize the data and check not empty before putting it into my database?

I am using PDO

My code:

```
    $nameO = $_POST["name"];
    $number = $_POST["number"];
    $city = $_POST["city"];


    try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO collection (name, citynumber, city) VALUES ('$number', '$nameO', '$city')";
        $sth = $db->query($sql);
    } catch(PDOExepction $e) {
        echo "SORRY!";
        exit;
    }

header( 'Location: www.site.com' ) ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use prepared statements:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO joukkueet (name, citynumber, city) VALUES (:number, :nameO, :city)";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth = $statement->execute( ['number' => $number, 'nameO' => $nameO, 'city' => $city] );
```

The things like `:number`, `:nameO` and `:city` are placeholders for values. Using the `$db->prepare` function in PDO creates a PDOStatement object. Now, this object has a method `execute`, and as you can see, we give it an array whose keys correspond to the placeholder names. So if you have `:nameO` in the prepared statement, the array should have a value with the key `nameO`, which PDO will safely add into the SQL code.

Of course, it is best that you check the parameters before just using them (e.g. length checks or making sure that `$number` is numeric). You ask to check that it is not empty.

Instead of simply:

```
$nameO = $_POST["name"];
$number = $_POST["number"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
```

I would suggest:

```
if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['number']) || empty($_POST['city'])) {
    exit('Please input all data!');
}
$nameO = $_POST["name"];
$number = $_POST["number"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
```

You may wish to handle the error another way than to stop with `exit`, of course. But a check with `empty()` can guarantee that there is at least some data in the variables.

Comment: You've covered 50% of the OP's question. *"and check not [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)"*

Comment: @ljacqu but how do i now run the code? I did put the code inside the `try` statement but it does nothing.

Comment: @Pullapooh Hmm? The SQL portion (first code block in my answer) should do exactly the same as your code before. Putting it in `try` is correct.

Comment: @ljacqu Do i need to put all three lines in the `try`block? If i do i just get a blank page if i click submit on the form. And it does not put data into the database.

Comment: @Pullapooh Is it possible that you've also copied my `if` check further up your file and that it is running `exit` ? Otherwise, try `var_dump($sth);` after the last line and make sure that error reporting is enabled.

Comment: @ljacqu I get: bool(true) And: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent. But now the data goes into my database.

Comment: bool(true) is good; it means it worked successfully. The warning happened because of the output of `var_dump()`. `header()` only works without _any_ output before. But you can remove `var_dump()` again; it was just to verify that `$sth` is indeed `true`.